# Removing a Product using button in laravel route link

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I created a sample products page using laravel framework,where I added a Remove button to remove that particular product onclick. below is the laravel route code added to the button

```
 <button onclick= "window.location= '{{ route('customer.wishlist.remove', $item->id) }}'" > Remove </button>
```

here the item id is automatically generated from database which can also be seen by inspecting the remove button code.

on clicking the Remove button the product is getting removed. but when i run the route link separately in the browser then also the product getting removed because the same location link is given to button also.

I want this operation work only on Remove button click. if i entered the route url directly it should'nt. How can i resist that.

please help me on this

thank you

Comment: Is this a `GET` route? You could/should use a `POST` form (including `@csrf`)

Comment: Try "location.href" instead of "window.location"

Comment: @Mihirajagia That won't prevent the url being called directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you're using get method so it can be directly accessible to the browser.

Now if you don't want to allow a user to directly access that URL then you need to make the request as `POST`

```
<button  onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('delete').submit();">Remove  </button >
<form id="delete" action="{{ route('customer.wishlist.remove', $item->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Make your route as `post`